# Can not execute subtask of a task in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7

I'm developing a system which works like following structure

[image]

Level1-sub-tasks are created by task via [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of .net 4.0, and Level2-sub-tasks are created by level1-sub-tasks similarly.

All tasks work file in debug, but when I deploy that on IIS server, all level2 sub tasks stops executing.

I'm not an experienced developer of iis, does it has any limitation for multi-level thread(task)?

Comment: I'm assuming you create these tasks when a request comes in.. do you wait for these tasks to finish before returning a response to the request?

Comment: @dcastro  Those tasks are running asynchronously, client won't need to wait for the tasks result and get the response immediately in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do spawn new threads while handling a request, make sure they have all finished before returning a response. You may think "I'm gonna return to the user asap, and leave a thread in the background saving stuff to the database." This is dangerous, mainly because the AppDomain may be recycled, aborting your background threads.

Alternatively, use the `IRegisteredObject` interface to tell asp.net you're doing some work in the background. The approach is detailed here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Do note that this is not fail-proof though, and that there are better approaches to this - it all depends on what you're trying to achieve. In most cases (e.g., sending out email notifications), the best solution is to schedule a task (in a separate process) that dequeues work items periodically.